# How vue know which image to display and being reactive from method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Recently I have signed up for VueMstery and I am lost. In order to understand code I have a habit of visualizing code and can't move if I cannot make sense of code. What I do not understand in the following code is

1. how function named `updateProduct` is updating the DOM with the passed in image and
2. how it know which image to display. (this point confuses me a lot)

Following is the code

```
<body>
<div class="nav-bar"></div>
<div id="app">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-image">
            <img :src="image" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
            <h1>{{products}}</h1>
            <p v-if='inStock'>In Stock</p>
            <p v-else>Out of stock</p>
            <p v-if='inventory <= 10'>Low on stock</p>

            <ul>
                <li v-for='detail in details'>{{detail}}</li>
            </ul>
            
            <div v-for='variant in variants'
                 class='color-box'
                 :style="{backgroundColor: variant.variantColor}"
                 @mouseover='updateProduct(variant.variantImage)'>
            </div>
            cart {{cart}}
            <button @click='addToCart'>
                Add to cart
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

and main.js

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        products: 'socks',
        image: './assets/vmSocks-green.jpg',
        inStock: true,
        inventory: 10,
        details: ["80% cotton", "20% polyester", "Gender-Neutral"],

        variants: [
            {
                variantId: 2234,
                variantColor: "green",
                variantImage: "./assets/vmSocks-green.jpg"
            },
            {
                variantId: 2235,
                variantColor: "blue",
                variantImage: "./assets/vmSocks-blue.jpg"
            },
        ],
        cart: 0
    },
    methods: {
        addToCart: function(){
            this.cart +=1
        },
        updateProduct: function(image){
            this.image = image;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the event handler which you've registered in the template:

```
@mouseover='updateProduct(variant.variantImage)'
```

Vue will run the function automatically when events fire. The function `updateProduct` just updates the value `image` in your data object. Vue detects any changes for that data and updates DOM when nessesary.

Also because your `img` tag depends on `image` property of data object:
`<img :src="image" alt="">`
you will see that image changes.

Comment: How does it know which item we have hovered e.g green box/text and find the matching green In the object

Comment: in template syntax it's something which looks like javascript closures.
`<div v-for='variant in variants' @mouseover='updateProduct(variant.variantImage)'>`  it makes different handler for each `variant` by taking `variant` variable to the closure. Probably this alternative will make sense: `const a = [1,2,3]; const handlers = a.map(x => () => console.log(x))` look that each function in handlers array is different and knows which number to print.

Comment: sorry I m not really sure I understood

Comment: You just make an array of functions:
`const handlers = variants.map(variant => () => updateProduct(variant.variantImage)` and add them as handlers to each `div` element separately. When the cursor hovers on `div`, the code knows which of these functions it should call.